# How to solve the error message: "Whitelabel Error Page" for Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I'm new with spring boot and I'm trying to make a project with Spring MVC + Spring Boot2 + JSP + Spring Data + DB Oracle.
When I run the simple application, The first message error I was been:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Apr 17 10:20:05 CEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I found a lot of documention about this error and I tested different solutions but nothing was fine for my problem. Below the tests I did:
1) I make sure that my main class was in the root package and I put the other packages int the sub level;
2) I used de @ComponentScan in the main class in this way @ComponentScan({"com.dashboard.demo.controller"});
3) in the application.properties I used this command server.servlet.context-path=/oee

This is my code:

Application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

server.servlet.context-path=/oee

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@serverIP:Port:DB11G
spring.datasource.username= Server name
spring.datasource.password= password

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect


# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql= true

server.port = 8091
```

Main

```
package com.dashboard.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OeeApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(OeeApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OeeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

OEEController

```
package com.dashboard.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.dashboard.demo.entities.OEE;
import com.dashboard.demo.service.OEEService;


@Controller
public class OEEController {

    @Autowired
    private OEEService oeeService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/oee}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listAll(Model model) 
    {
        List<OEE> oee = oeeService.SelDevice();

        model.addAttribute("OEE",oee);

        return "oee";
    }

}
```

OEEServiceImpl

```
package com.dashboard.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.dashboard.demo.entities.OEE;
import com.dashboard.demo.repository.OEERepository;

@Service
@Transactional
public class OEEServiceImpl implements OEEService{

    @Autowired
    private OEERepository oeeRepository;

    @Override
    public List<OEE> SelDevice() 
    {
        return oeeRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

OEERepository

```
package com.dashboard.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.dashboard.demo.entities.OEE;
import com.dashboard.demo.entities.OEEid;

@Repository
public interface OEERepository extends JpaRepository<OEE, OEEid>
{


}
```

I'm managing a composite key and I've create a class for the composite key and another to manage the entity. I'm catching the error int this package.

```
package com.dashboard.demo.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Embeddable
public class OEEid implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4512114330774744082L;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "MSO_GIORNO_LAV")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "MSO_MACCHINA")
    private String device;

    public OEEid(Date date, String device) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        this.device = device;
    }


}

package com.dashboard.demo.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;


import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MES_OEE")
@Data
public class OEE implements Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7738922358421962399L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private OEEid oeeID;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "MSO_QUANTITA")
    private int amount;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "MSO_OEE")
    private float oee;
}
```

oee.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<c:url value="/css/main.css" var="jstlCss" />
<link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header>
   <h1>Spring MVC + JSP + JPA + Spring Boot 2</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="starter-template">
   <h1>Users List</h1>
   <table
    class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Device</th>
     <th>Amount</th>
     <th>OEE</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${OEE}" var="oee">
     <tr>
        <td>${oee.oeeID.date}</td>
        <td>${oee.oeeID.device}</td>
        <td>${oee.amount}</td>
        <td>${oee.oee}</td>
     </tr>
    </c:forEach>
   </table>
  </div>

 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript"
  src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions to solve this error message?
Thanks

This is my project directory
[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with jsp, but this error indicates that you try to access an endpoint which not exists. Are you sure that your client calls `localhost:8091/oee`

Comment: I Think so... I made another application without spring data. I had the same error, but I change the level of my packages and now it's working.

Comment: Only one different is the port 8080

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try by removing this `server.servlet.context-path=/oee` from properties file and try with `localhost:8080/oeee`

Comment: Yes, oee.jsp is in WEB-INF/jsp

Comment: can you please attach your project directory screen?

Comment: please keep your `OeeApplication.class` under this package `com.dashboard` and try again.

Comment: I had already done this proof, but it wasn't work.. Thanks for your help. Any others suggestions. I attached my project directory image above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211884/discussion-between-devprakash-and-scripta14).

Comment: Sorry I was busy, thanks for your availability. If you are still available we may check the error message.